# Almacenar datos de un input temporalmente para una respuesta con multicita

Tags: php

¿Cómo lo hago para que cuando le de al botón de Responder en lugar de llevarme directamente a la página de reply.php almacene los datos temporalmente para poder citar más de una respuesta clicando en el botón de responder de distintos comentarios y llevándome finalmente a la página reply.php donde pueda jugar con esos datos? Con el código que tengo ahora solamente puedo citar a una persona, no tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo para citar a más de una a la vez.

```
<form action="../reply.php" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="usuarioID" value="' . $u_id . '">
   <input type="hidden" name="mensaje" value="' . $mensaje . '">
   <button name="reply" type="submit">Responder</button>
</form>
```

reply.php

```
$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['usuarioID']);
$mensaje = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['mensaje']);

<form method="POST" action="' . replyComments($connection) . '">
<input type="hidden" name="usuario_respuesta" value="' . $_SESSION['u_id'] . '">
<input type="hidden" name="usuario" value="' . $usuario . '">
<input type="hidden" name="mensaje" value="' . $mensaje . '">
<textarea name="texto">
<span class="cita">De ' . $usuario . ': ' . $mensaje .'</span>
</textarea>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Enviar respuesta</button>
</form>
```

La función lo único que hace es recoger los datos del input y textarea y registrarlos en la base de datos a través de un INSERT INTO.

Comment: Cual es el contenido de **/reply.php** . debes ser mas especifico con tu pregunta para poder ayudarte

Comment: actualizado a ver si se entiende mejor

Answer (score 2):

No termina de quedarme claro lo que intentas pero probare a darte una respuesta intentando acercarme todo lo que pueda a la solución que necesitas.

Para comenzar necesitarás un `array` para guardar las **respuestas**, las respuestas serán también un `array` por lo que se va a trabajar con un **array bidimensional**.

El `array` que guarda las respuestas va a ser una *variable de sesión* para no perder los datos cada vez que crees una nueva respuesta.

Debemos guardar las respuestas cuando le demos a submit, como no quieres que te lleve directamente a `reply.php` pondras en el `action`el mismo nombre de la página (luego haremos que se envie a `reply.php`).

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="usuarioID" value="' . $u_id . '">
<input type="hidden" name="mensaje" value="' . $mensaje . '">
<input type="submit" name="añadir" value="Añadir usuario">
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" formaction="../reply.php">

</form>
<?php

start_session();
if(!isset($_SESSION["resultados"])){
    $_SESSION["resultados"] = array();
}


if(isset[$_GET["añadir"]] || isset[$_GET["enviar"]]){
    if(isset[$_GET["usuarioID"]]){
        $usuarioID = $_GET["usuarioID"];
    }
    if(isset[$_GET["mensaje"]]){
        $mensaje = $_GET["mensaje"];
    }
}

$respuesta = array ($usuarioID,$mensaje);
array_push($_SESSION["resultados"], $respuesta);
?>
```

De esta manera guardamos las respuestas en una variable de sesión.

Para mostrar el contenido de el array con hacer un `var_dumb()` bastaría.

<sub>Nota: Menciono como se muestra, no como se recorre, para recorrer necesitas `for`.</sub>

```
<?php
  var_dump($_SESSION["resultados"]);
?>
```

<sub>Nota 2: Puede que haya algun error en el código ya que no me ha dado tiempo para probarlo</sub>

Comment: Ahora le echo un vistazo, gracias!

Comment: @Kakotas7 puede que no te funcione al principio porque lo he hecho practicamente de cabeza, si tiene algun fallo me comentas.